# How to find the correct combination for a key's ESC sequence in iTerm2

Tags: macos, bash, vim, macvim, iterm2

I have been trying to fix a terminal emulator behaviour in a situation where MacVim is running in iTerm2. I have the following key combinations assigned to individual actions in my Vim setup:

```
F10, action_A
CTRL-F10, action_B
SHIFT-F10, action_C
```

When I use those combinations in iTerm2 with Vim, `SHIFT-F10` is interpreted correctly as `action_A`. However, the emulator is not able to distinguish between `CTRL-F10` and `F10` because of the esc sequence issue.

What I have noticed is that iTerm2 is configured to send `Esc+[21;2~` whenever `SHIFT-F10` is pressed. So by assigning the same sequence to `CTRL-F10` I managed to force `SHIFT-F10` and `CTRL-F10` to perform `action_C` and `F10` to perform `action_A`.

This proves that by sending the right esc sequence, one should be able to force iTerm2 to distinguish between different keys.

The question is: If `SHIFT-F10` is associated with `Esc+[21;2~` how do we find what `CTRL-F10` is associated with? How do I find the esc sequence that represents `CTRL-F10`? or maybe the Hex Code? (as iTerm2 provides the option of sending a Hex Code to the terminal session)

Comment: Its under Preferences -> Profile -> Keys, Add or change as nessesary

Comment: Hi @FDinoff, thanks for the help. I am trying to find the actual values (esc+) or hex that represents `CTRL-F10` so I can input those into that section: `Preferences -> Profile -> Keys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-F10 could be sent as "\e[21;5~", using the action 'Send text with special chars'. Complete answer is here: [how do I know what CTRL-F10 is associated with?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/4vzOE1W7Lmg)

Answer (score 1):

In insert mode in vim, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and press your keys. This will insert the escape literally along with the rest of the control code for this key combo. This is convenient when you're already editing a config file.

You can similarly run something like `od -t x1` (for a hex dump) or even just cat, which doesn't interpret input, and just press your key combo there:

```
$ od -t x1
^[[21~
0000000 1b 5b 32 31 7e 0a
0000006

$
```

(press Ctrl-D once or twice to exit)

Comment: the problem is, as we are trying to force iTerm2 to map a specific esc sequence to a key combination, we cannot really use a process that runs in iTerm2. When I hit `F10` and `CTRL-F10` they both will give me `^[[21~` I am trying to find the values for `CTRL-F10` and I cannot do that in a terminal. Is there a chart or an application that will give me the code for `CTRL-F10`.

Comment: I don't follow. If you're remapping ctrl-f10, can't you choose an arbitrary sequence? Remapping ctrl-f10 in your terminal to whatever ctrl-f10 produces in your terminal sounds like a no op.

Comment: Hi, my question has been answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/4vzOE1W7Lmg If you have a mapping that goes as <C-F10> in vim, vim would expect that specific signal.